# Proper request for showing image on DLNA server without Cling

Tags: curl, dlna

I can use the following to show an mp4 on a DLNA Server (I know the meta info is wrong but see below).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <u:SetAVTransportURI xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1">
      <InstanceID>0</InstanceID>
      <CurrentURI><![CDATA[http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4]]></CurrentURI>
        <CurrentURIMetaData>
          <DIDL-Lite xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/"
              xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
              xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/"
              xmlns:dlna="urn:schemas-dlna-org:metadata-1-0/">
            <item id="sample" parentID="0" restricted="0">
              <dc:title>Title of Image</dc:title>
              <res protocolInfo="http-get:*:image/jpeg:DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_OP=01">
                http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4
              </res>
            </item>
          </DIDL-Lite>
        </CurrentURIMetaData>
      </u:SetAVTransportURI>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

I then use a curl command for setting AvTransport and then Play and that will play the video on the DLNA Server. If I ONLY change the url to a jpeg image, this does not work. No errors are returned, the screen blips and the image is not displayed. I have verified the image URL works and can be displayed on the DLNA server using a Cling java app but I want to get away from using Cling as it is no longer maintained and I don't need a full DLNA implementation for my app.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. The `<CurrentURIMetaData>` tag has to replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`